# Can I share the free Windows keys my college provides?

Tags: windows, product-key

My college gives us free Windows keys and a friend asked me for one. Should I give him one or is there any danger?

---

I know It's against the rules but the plan is: I see the key on my screen, I tell him, and he activates windows 10. How can they know I'm not the one using the pc?

Comment: This depends entirely on the license under which the keys were provided. you will have to get clarification from the school on what type of licensing was used to obtain the keys, and from there, check with microsoft to determine whether those keys are transferable by an end user. They almost certianly are not. about the only licenses that are transferable are OEM licenses, which once installed on a box, follow that box even if the ownership of the box changes.

Comment: I know it's against the rules, but can they find out?

Comment: @SotirisCodv, Yes if the license is owned by the college, they have the legal right with Microsoft to check if the key is currently in use. All they have to do is call Microsoft.. If it is against the rules, I advise you not to do it. Such an action may be illegal if they consider it stealing.

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: when I wrote this, I had read 'colleague', not 'college'. A school or university might have a collective license for all students - but certainly not for non-students.]

There are no *free* Windows keys.

Those are either fake or stolen, either way they don't get you very far. Either they don't work, or it's illegal to use them (just because a lot of people do it, doesn't make it less illegal).

Of course, theoretically he could be buying them from Microsoft for 100$ a pop and handing them out for free. That would be legal, but I doubt it severely.

Comment: As you point out the license key provided by a College to a student is being paid for.  It might be free to that student but it isn't actually free.

Answer (score 0):

Those Windows keys were most likely issued as part of software license for your school. Most likely they are part of some academic edition (AE) licensing package, which has special pricing and terms of use. Your school paid for them even if from your viewpoint they could appear as free.

If you are not the person eligible to manage these software licenses for your organization (and related keys and Windows installations), your are expected to handle the keys as sensitive information and you cannot share them **even** with your schoolmates or colleagues from your organization.

You should handle potential request for a key from a schoolmate or colleague this way:

> I am not authorized to provide you the key. Should the key be available for you as it was for me, please obtain it in official way by contacting __________ department.

This way you are also defending yourself from committing unlawful action, because any sharing of the key would be illegal.